# Change Bootstrap color using javascript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I want to change some bootstrap variable values using JavaScript. I know I could use SCSS but the requirement I have right now is that it needs to happen on click so I think JavaScript is the way to go.

Here's what I have right now. It doesn't work though. Console message appears to be writing correctly but the UI colors don't change.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="UpdateColor()">CHANGE COLOR ON CLICK</button>
<h3 class="text-primary">WHEN BUTTON IS CLICKED MY COLOR SHOULD CHANGE</h3>

<script>
    function UpdateColor() {
        var root = document.querySelector(':root');
        var rs = getComputedStyle(root);

        console.log('before', rs.getPropertyValue('--primary'));
        root.style.setProperty('--primary', 'red');
        console.log('after', rs.getPropertyValue('--primary'));
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be using CSS variables...

add "style" tag:

```
<style>
  .text-primary {
    color: var(--primary);
  }
</style>
```

result:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="UpdateColor()">CHANGE COLOR ON CLICK</button>
<h3 class="text-primary">WHEN BUTTON IS CLICKED MY COLOR SHOULD CHANGE</h3>
<style>
  .text-primary {
    color: var(--primary);
  }
</style>
<script>
  function UpdateColor() {
    var root = document.querySelector(':root');
    var rs = getComputedStyle(root);

    console.log('before', rs.getPropertyValue('--primary'));
    root.style.setProperty('--primary', 'red');
    console.log('after', rs.getPropertyValue('--primary'));
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This one works but the challenge is that I am using bootstrap v4.6 and overriding it with style tag won't cover other stuff like :hover, :focus, etc... I was kind of hoping a simple approach where I can change a root variable and it does the work but worst case, I'll probably use this one and override everything including hover, focus events

Comment: @MADJOE
You can use a custom theme, and prepare multiple theme css files, and then switch the **href** value of the **link** tag when you click the button.